# How to sort based on excel or sheets column data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, google-spreadsheets

I have a form that submits to a google sheet with the following columns:
Entry Date, First Name, Last Name,  Address, Phone, Email, Member Type, Vote Date,  Result

(The 'result' column has three options, Approved, Denied, Pending.)

I want to have three sheets, each sheet showing the corresponding person's information based on the "result" column. 
Sheet2 will contain the list of all people marked 'Approved', 
Sheet3 will contain all the people marked "Pending", 
Sheet4 will contain a list of all the people marked "Denied".

How would I do this? Tried a Vlookup formula but couldn't get to work.

Here is the link to my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13g9p5jbbxIP8m5Y8Fp_vUQI-oCxkIwn-XShfe54mEzs/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can create unique values by occurrence number of Result values, to lookup and get your data. Although I have already updated the worksheet in google sheets, here are brief information and a link to help.

1. Firstly, I created unique values with combining Result and occurrence numbers with help of **COUNTIF** function. The trick is to use *expanded range*. This creates values like: *Approved1, Debied1, Approved2, etc..* So I wrote the formula below in *FormList's M column* and copy down:

   `=L2&COUNTIF($L$2:L2,L2)`
   [image: unique values]
2. Secondly; In *Approved** sheet, I wrote an INDEX-MATCH function combination to search *unique* values I created and column titles and get the data from *FormList* sheet. Of course I copied this formula to all table. **Note:** While the **ROW** function generates incremental numbers for unique values, the **IFERROR** returns empty strings for **INDEX** errors.

   `=IFERROR(INDEX(FormList!$A$2:$L$8,MATCH("Approved"&ROW()-1,FormList!$M$2:$M$8,0),MATCH(A$1,FormList!$A$1:$L$1,0)),"")`
   [image: approved]
3. Finally; I repeated same approach for *Pending* and *Denied* sheets as well.

Here is a brief tutorial of what I did with a simple data: [How to get nth match with VLOOKUP](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-get-nth-match-with-vlookup/)

Comment: @JoshGorrell - If this answers your question, can you indicate that by clicking on the tick to the left of the answer?  Maybe you would like to give the answer an upvote too if you thought the answer was a great answer.